# A very confusing "ParseException: Unparseable date" (SimpleDateFormat) error

Tags: java, windows, macos

I run a program with `SimpleDateFormat.parse()` on two computers: a Mac OS X laptop and a Windows desktop. On the desktop, the date parsing throws a `ParseException`.

The code is simple: `new SimpleDateFormat("E, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z").parse("Wed, 4 Jul 2001 12:08:56 -0700")`

`Locale.getDefault` returns `en_US` on both computers.

`java -version` returns `1.6.0_65` on the Mac, and `1.7.0_21` on the Windows computer throwing the `ParseException`.

I'm totally out of ideas as why the `ParseException` happens on the Windows environment. Would someone have a clue?

Cheers.

Comment: Try `EEE` instead of `E`

Comment: Have you tried removing bits of your date and date format in turn, to identify which particular characters are causing the exception?

Comment: @DavidWallace When I remove the 3-letter day, it works: `new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z").parse("4 Jul 2001 12:08:56 -0700")` works. I tried putting back the three-letter day, with `EEE` as an alternative to `E` in the `SimpleDateFormat`, didn't solve the issue.

Comment: You might want to double-check the "Region and Language" settings on the user account in question.  Windows allows mix-and-match settings which can't be represented by Locale, so perhaps Java is using those rather than behaving as documented?  Also, is the Windows computer in the same timezone as the Mac?

Comment: OK, so it's the "Wed" which is giving the problem.  What is returned if you run `new DateFormatSymbols().getShortWeekdays()` ?

Comment: @HarryJohnston: you found the cause and the solution. Although my Windows is in English, the calendar is in Swedish because this is where I live and I selected that at the Windows installation. I went to "Region and Language" settings, changed the format to "English (United States)" and it solved the issue! Thank you so much. If you can write that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @DavidWallace you were on the right track, see my comment above. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows allows mix-and-match internationalization settings, so if you change your calendar format (in the "Region and Language" control panel) it affects Java's date parsing without affecting the result of `Locale.GetDefault`.

Whether this is the correct behaviour is debatable.  It doesn't appear to be documented.

Answer (score 0):

That is indeed quite strange.  I just tried the same code on my Windows 8 machine, running jdk1.7.0_09 and I get a valid result with no exceptions.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        java.util.Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("E, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z").parse("Wed, 4 Jul 2001 12:08:56 -0700");
        System.out.println("Date: " + date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

Have you tried surrounding it in a try {} catch {} block to see what the exception says?

Comment: I've run it on Linux on OpenJDK 1.7.0_25, and on Windows XP on Oracle 1.7.0_25 .  Both work fine without throwing ParseException, as expected.

Comment: This is what comments are for.

Comment: @jackchanner I tried your exact code, triggered the `ParseException` on the Windows computer. Replaced 1.7.0_21 to _45 just for the sake of it, and it didn't solve the issue

Comment: @Blackbird - When you tried the exact code on your Windows computer, what did the VM complain about? What were the Exception details?  Did you compile the class on Windows or on MAC OS X?  What happens if you compile and run on the same platform, or did you try that already?

Comment: @jackchanner the solution was found, see my comment on the post above. Thanks for your time :)